# Spring Security with basic auth redirecting to /error for invalid credentials

Tags: spring, security, authentication, basic-authentication, credentials

I have a spring boot application running with spring security using basic auth.
When proper basic auth credentials are supplied, everything is good, but for incorrect auth credentials, spring comes up with a `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported` exception.

According to the logs, the authentication failure has been identified by spring, but that's not what comes out.

`2015-08-12 09:33:10.922  INFO 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Aug 12 09:33:10 AEST 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
2015-08-12 09:33:10.927 TRACE 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@483e1fc6]
2015-08-12 09:33:10.927 DEBUG 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/myapplication/error]
2015-08-12 09:33:10.927 TRACE 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@331bb032] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-08-12 09:33:10.927 TRACE 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/error]
2015-08-12 09:33:10.927 TRACE 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping@69e79b9b] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-08-12 09:33:10.927 TRACE 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@27cc0354] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-08-12 09:33:10.927 DEBUG 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2015-08-12 09:33:10.928 DEBUG 16988 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported`

With the above logs & after debugging the spring source, I found out that upon identifying that the credentials are incorrect, spring creates a BadCredentials exception and then tries to redirect to “/error”, this redirection is what causes the HttpMethodNotAllowed exception.(my application doesn't have a /error endpoint).

I tried to tell spring not to use /error by configuring the following,

`public class ServerCustomization extends ServerProperties {

```
@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

    super.customize(container);
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, null));

}`
```

This will make spring stop spitting out the HttpMethodnotallowed exception and make it come up with a 401(Unauthorized), BUT my this exception is not caught by my Exception handler (configured using `@ControllerAdvice`).

I also tried configuring a custom authentication entry point like below without any luck.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

AlwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint alwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint = 
        new AlwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint();


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().xssProtection().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and().csrf().disable();

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(alwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint);
}

public class AlwaysSendUnauthorized401AuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public final void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

}

Is there any way we can specify to spring not to redirect to /error and return the Bad Credentials Exception ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created a sample Spring Boot app, with the following security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().xssProtection()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable();

        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());

    }
}
```

When entering an invalid username/password (anything other than test/password), I get the following response:

```
{"timestamp":1439381390204,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/"}
```

This error is returned by `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController` class, which if you have a look does define two methods with `@RequestMapping("/error")` - `errorHtml` and `error`. Since you're building an API, it's the second one that should be invoked and I would say that's the "correct" behaviour!

So, first thing, check that you're getting to the `BasicErrorController` when authentication fails. If you are, make sure that you're hitting the `error` method NOT `errorHtml`.

If none of the above proves helpful, check whether someone has overriden the default behaviour of the error controller. One common (and valid) extension is to implement your own `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes` to change the default error payload. But it's just as easy to replace the entire `BasicErrorController` with a non-standard implementation, so check for that in your application.

If all else fails and you're adamant that you want to disable Spring's default error handling (which I don't recommend), try adding this to your configuration:

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})`

What this will do is ensure that the error controllers are not loaded into the application context.

Comment: Thanks @grigori for pointing me in the right direction. There was indeed a non standard implementation of the BasicErrorController which was causing the problem. Using a proper error controller fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, for me the mvc-exclude fixed it, sometimes I love the defaults of SpringBoot, and sometimes not :) But that reminds me of not doing a magic @EnableAutoConfiguration but instead only a subset of specifically needed *Configuration's.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of `http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint` you should be using `http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint`. For form based authentication, this is working for me:

```
http
    .formLogin()
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
        ...
    ...
```

For the authentication failure handler, Spring's `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` can be used. When instantiated without any parameter, it would do what we want:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}
```

[This](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/security/LemonSecurityConfig.java) is my complete security config file, in case it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay, will try this out in a bit and let you know how it went

Comment: I did try both your solutions but no luck yet. the `formLogin()` doesn't look correct as mine is a restrul API. the other suggestion about the `authenticationEntryPoint` looked promising but did not yield anything.