# Spring Security + Basic Auth + API return 404 instead 401

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a spring boot application running with spring security using basic auth. When proper basic auth credentials are supplied, controller method is invoked, but for incorrect auth credentials, I am getting a 404 Not Found instead of a 401 Unauthorized.

This is my Spring Security Config

```
@Configuration
public static class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .antMatcher("/useradmin/api")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()).and().csrf().disable();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("default").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

I have reviewed [Spring Security with basic auth redirecting to /error for invalid credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954292/spring-security-with-basic-auth-redirecting-to-error-for-invalid-credentials) and if I exclude `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class` from Auto Configuration classes I get 401. However, if I leave it auto configured I only get 404 and actually it's not being redirected to `/error` as before mentioned question says.

I have created my own implementation of `BasicErrorController`, I put a breakpoint on getError method and it's never reached so I assume something else is catching response and changing its status from 401 to 404.

What else could be the root of this problem?

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue ?